# how do I hide a button on unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to create a button that when you press it, a new button will open. I know how to make both buttons, but I can't manage to hide the first button once clicked.

This is my code so far:

```
#pragma strict

function Start () 
{
}

function Update () 
{
}

var isButtonVisible  :  boolean  =  true;  

var buttonRectangle  :  Rect     =  Rect(100, 100, 100, 50);

function OnGUI ()
{
    var NewButton = GUI.Button(Rect (Screen.width / 2 - 75, Screen.height / 2 -25,150,50), "this is also a button");

    if ( isButtonVisible ) 
    {
        if ( GUI.Button(Rect (Screen.width / 2 - 75, Screen.height / 2 -25,150,50), "button") ) 
        {
            isButtonVisible = false;


            if ( isButtonVisible ) 
            {
                return NewButton;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to programing so this question might be a bit unclear.

Comment: I guess something is missing in the code that you've posted. The `if ( isButtonVisible )` will never return a `NewButton` because you are setting `isButtonVisible` to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with "Happy Apple's" solution, and just to expand on this if you wanted to integrate reverse functionality you can simply alter the code as follows:

```
var isButtonVisible : boolean = true;
var buttonRectangle : Rect = Rect(100, 100, 100, 50);

function OnGUI ()

{

if(isButtonVisible)
{

    if(GUI.Button(Rect(Screen.width/2 - 75,Screen.height/2 - 25,150,50),"button"))
    {
        isButtonVisible = false;
    }

}
else
{

    if(GUI.Button(Rect(Screen.width/2 - 75,Screen.height/2 -25,150,50),"this is also a button"))
    {
        isButtonVisible = true;
    }

}

}
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It was just a logic error. Firstly you're checking if ( isButtonVisible ) inside another if ( isButtonVisible ) bracket, which is redundant. Secondly if we know the condition we want for the second button to appear (first button being clicked) and the boolean flag for said button being clicked (isButtonVisible == false) we can just branch the isButtonVisible condition to display the second button when this is false.

Assuming you wanted a first button to make another one appear and hide itself on click, this should do what you wanted (though it will only logically flow one way, that is the first button will hide itself and show the second button, but not reversable). So your original code was pretty close.

```
var isButtonVisible  :  boolean  =  true;  

var buttonRectangle  :  Rect     =  Rect(100, 100, 100, 50);

function OnGUI ()
{
    if ( isButtonVisible ) 
    {
        if ( GUI.Button(Rect (Screen.width / 2 - 125, Screen.height / 2 -175,150,50), "button") ) 
        {
            isButtonVisible = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var NewButton = GUI.Button(Rect (Screen.width / 2 - 75, Screen.height / 2 -25,150,50), "this is also a button");
    }
}
```

Admittedly there's several better ways to implement this but I hope it solved your problem.