# Disable the GUI when the character moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i already make the player character to move to it is destination (animate the character to move to that destination), i wanted to disable the GUI button when the player character is moving, but i can't get it and work it out. Could you guys help me?

Here is the code:

```
public class UserPlayer : Player 
{
    public override void TurnUpdate()
    {
       //Moving animation
       if (positionQueue.Count > 0) 
        {
          GUI.enabled = false; // This is the one that i want when the character still moving (animation still moving), disabled the GUI. But i can't get it
          transform.position += (positionQueue[0] - transform.position).normalized * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

          if (Vector3.Distance(positionQueue[0], transform.position) <= 0.1f) 
          {
             transform.position = positionQueue[0];
             positionQueue.RemoveAt(0);

          if (positionQueue.Count == 0) 
          {
              actionPoints--;
          } 
         }
       }

       base.TurnUpdate();
    }

    public override void TurnOnGUI() 
    {
        base.TurnOnGUI();
    }
}

public class Player : MonoBehaviour 
{
    //for movement animation
    public List<Vector3> positionQueue = new List<Vector3>();

    public virtual void TurnUpdate()
    {
       if (actionPoints <= 0) 
        {
            actionPoints = 2;
            magicAttacking = false;
            moving = false;
            attacking = false;      
            GameManager.instance.NextTurn();
       }
    }

     public virtual void TurnOnGUI()
      {
        if (GameManager.instance.currentPlayerIndex == 0 || GameManager.instance.currentPlayerIndex == 2)
        {
            //ToolTip Text
            move = GUI.Button(buttonRect, new GUIContent("Move", "Move the Player"));
            GUI.Label(tooltipRect, GUI.tooltip, label1);

            GUI.tooltip = null;

            //Move Button
            if (move)
            {
               if (!moving)
               {
                  GameManager.instance.RemoveTileHighlights();
                  moving = true;
                  attacking = false;
                  GameManager.instance.HighlightTilesAt(gridPosition, Color.blue, movementPerActionPoint);
               }

               else
               {
                  moving = false;
                  attacking = false;
                  GameManager.instance.RemoveTileHighlights();
               }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by disable? From what I can see, while the character is moving, the `moving` parameter should be preventing the button from doing anything. Do you mean you want the button to be non-pressable and greyed out, sort of like the way window forms do it?

Answer (score 0):

Your question has been already made, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285568/how-do-i-hide-a-button-on-unity).

Adapt your code in this way:

```
public virtual void TurnOnGUI() {
  if (GameManager.instance.currentPlayerIndex == 0 || GameManager.instance.currentPlayerIndex == 2) {
  ...
  if(!moving) {
     move = GUI.Button(buttonRect, new GUIContent("Move", "Move the Player"));
     GUI.Label(tooltipRect, GUI.tooltip, label1);
  }      
  ...
  }
}
```