# Hide Button in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a begginer in unity3d and I work on a simple game , there are some buttons and I want to hide them when I click on one of them.
Can anyone help me to do that in C# code?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I hide a button on unity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285568/how-do-i-hide-a-button-on-unity)

Comment: actually, not sure that's the best duplicate. looks like an older approach. i don't see the solution i'm expecting, which is simply to called `setActive` on the gameObject.

Comment: 1. We are not here to do your work. Show us some code and we show you what you did wrong or what you could do better ;)
2. Give us more information. What do you mean with "hide the button"? Disabling, set inactive,...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### To Create a UI Button

You can use the Unity's UI System to create buttons. Right click the **Hierarchy**, click **UI**, then select **Button**. A canvas will be created with the button. In the Button's Inspector you will see a small panel on the very bottom that says "On Click()". Click the plus arrow. Attach your script to an empty game object, by right clicking the Hierarchy and clicking "Create Empty". Find your script from your Project folder and drag the script to the empty game object you just created in your Hierarchy. Then click on the Button, that you created inside the canvas, again, and drag the empty game object to the little box that says "None". Click the "No Function" box to reveal a drop down, and find the function that you want to execute when you press the button.

### Scripting

You can reference the button you are trying to hide like a `GameObject` like this:

```
GameObject button;
void Start() {
    button = GameObject.Find ("Button");
}
```

In this example, `ButtonClicked()` is the function that you have selected to execute in the inspector once the button is clicked. You would use the `SetActive()` method to hide it or make it reappear:

```
void ButtonClicked() {
    button.SetActive(false);   
}
```

[Unity Manual SetActive()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html)

[UI Button](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Button.html)

Comment: actually, I don't know how to make my button a gameobject it's my first step in GUI in unity

Comment: Since comments aren't meant to last, I edited my answer to answer your second question. If my answer answered your question, then please mark it as the correct answer. The check mark is under the down arrow of the voting buttons.

Answer (score 15):

You can attach this script to your button.

```
Button buttonToHide;

void Start(){
   buttonToHide = GetComponent<Button>();

   buttonToHide.onClick.AddListener(() => HideButton());
}

void HideButton(){
   buttonToHide.gameObject.setActive(false);
}
```

Basically what does the code do is, adding the listener event to the button. so everytime you click, it will call `HideButton()` which hide the button in hierachy.

Answer (score 6):

The absolutely simplest you can do is to use the Unity built in functions.

- Select the button in your Scene/Hierarchy
- Scroll down to the Button (Script) in the Inspector
- Click the + button in OnClick
- Drag the Button game object from Hierarchy into the now created Empty slot "None (Object)"
- Click the drop down, Select: GameObject.SetActive
- Don't check the check box
- Press play and try it

[Button in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFkfm.png)

Answer (score 4):

```
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public UnityEngine.UI.Button Button;


    public void onClickEvent() 
    {
        //Hide button
        Button.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour{
    public Button Examplebtn;
}

public void onClickExampleEvent{
   Examplebtn.interactable=false;
}
```

Comment: This will not hide it tho just disable it.